# Change font in Asymptote

Tags: fonts, asymptote

How can I to change the font in Asymptote (to Palatino) with TeXMaker?
If I try

`usepackage{"mathpazo"};`

I get this error message:

```
test.asy: 4.11: cannot call 'guide operator spec(pair z, int p)' with
parameters '(string, int)'
```

Without `usepackage{"mathpazo"}` everything works fine

Comment: Are you aware of the *texpreamble(..)* command?  See the bottom of [this page from the manual](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Frames-and-pictures.html).

Comment: If you are putting this as a line in the `asy` file, I think the line you want is `usepackage("mathpazo");`. The line `texpreamble("\usepackage{mathpazo}");` will also work.

Comment: Yes, thank you. 'texpreamble("\usepackage{mathpazo}");' works fine, while 'usepackage("mathpazo");' leads to the strange error message. I thought the two statements are equivalent according to the asymptote manual, but in this (my) case certainly not

Comment: @Gertjan: The manual is correct, they are equivalent
and (just checked) both works equivalently fine.
The error shows up because you used wrong syntax: `usepackage{"mathpazo"};` instead of `usepackage("mathpazo");`, 
that is `{}` instead of correct `()`.